# IP address v4/v6 equivalence testing

Tags: c++, boost-asio, ip-address, equivalence, websocket++

Is it possible to test IP addresses for equivalence in a dual stack environment using both IPv4 and IPv6?  If so, how?

My application uses [websocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) on top of Boost ASIO.

As an example, on my LAN, one application connects to another listening on `192.168.1.2`, but using [this answer's IP address getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601763/how-to-get-ip-addresss-of-boostasioiptcpsocket)

```
std::string s = socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string();
```

gives `::ffff:192.168.1.3` as the client's address.

The problem is that `.2` will have its own node list with the original v4 address for `.3`, so by simple string comparison of the getter above vs a v4 version held on disk, it will seek a redundant connection to `.3` even though already connected.

I've further read that things can get more complicated since by this [dotted quad notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Presentation), `::ffff:192.0.2.128` is also `::ffff:c000:0280`.

I am building a p2p application that accepts addresses from untrusted sources, so to prevent redundant connections, I need to be able to absolutely test for equivalence.

Can my intent be implemented?  If so, how?  If not, should I only use v4?  I'd much rather include future capabilities now rather than worrying about integration later.

Comment: do you want to restrict the protocols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just use the `ip::tcp::address` classes' `operator==`.

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/371d8aeea6f70651)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::address;

address from_string_ip6(std::string const& ip)
{
    address a = address::from_string(ip);
    if (a.is_v4())
        return boost::asio::ip::address_v6::v4_mapped(a.to_v4());
    else
        return a;
}

int main()
{
    address a = from_string_ip6("192.0.2.111");
    address b = from_string_ip6("::ffff:192.0.2.111");
    address c = from_string_ip6("::ffff:c000:026f");

    assert(a == b);
    assert(a == c);
    assert(b == c);
}
```

**Update** If you want to include name-resolution: [ipv4 and ipv6 from any valid address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196949/ipv4-and-ipv6-from-any-valid-address/24200074#24200074)

Comment: The whole trick is to simply use the class as intended (encapsulating the domain knowledge) - and not bother about the string representation at all. Live a happy life and have a beer instead (share one with the boost devs!)

Comment: I'm not a boost dev. What do you need a pubkey for? AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIHOn6tEWqduGI076kYoo32EwRT6oCHbJtzS34Z0x4Vi2 (by the time that took, you can tell I don't use BSD)

Comment: you'll need to normalize all addresses to IPv6 addresses to do this. Incoming addresses via Asio/WebSocket++ should already be normalized . If you need to compare *raw* IPv4 addresses you should use the from_string constructor demonstrated above then use the boost ip::address_v6::v4_mapped function to convert to the IPv4 mapped format. (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v6/v4_mapped.html)

Comment: @Gracchus Good morning :) Good call there. Here's what zaphoyd meant: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/371d8aeea6f70651) (And, you found things I do not know/realize :))